# Building uWSGI with bazel

Tags: uwsgi, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a simple example package served with uwsgi, that I'm trying to switch from building with makefile rules to bazel.
The WORKSPACE file that, in addition to loading `rules_python` and other default stuff (registering toolchains) also gets uwsgi as follows

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "new_git_repository")

new_git_repository(
    name = "uwsgi",
    remote = "git@github.com:unbit/uwsgi.git",
    commit = "ca8bc6acc98b2c062b5b00668acd851e210fcbca",
    build_file_content = """
...
"""
)
```

What I can't quite get my head around is how to build `uwsgi`. Technically, you're building a C package. However, I'm building it using the provided python script (`uwsgiconfig.py`) and my configuration file (I'll call it `myconf.ini` that I manually copy into the `uwsgi/buildconf/` directory then build the package using `python uwsgiconfig.py --build myconfig`
This is the stage I'm (hopefully) trying to accomplish with bazel. However, I'm not sure if I should be using a `cc_binary` or a `py_binary` rule for to build uwsgi.

 Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to use uwsgi in a python project or are you using the C interface?

Comment: In a python project

Comment: Have you tried using the pip package?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a few bug fixes and flags that regard the usage of HTTP 1.1's chunked transfer encoding that didn't make it to the latest available release via `pip`. Hence why we're resorting to building a particular commit number from github for the package.

Comment: Have you considered building the standalone ".whl", and uploading that to a server? Then download and consume the .whl file using Bazel instead.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No problem, [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/ac5b9736356638df6669376be73fa17b05ab1bf9/python/pip_install/repositories.bzl) might be a good resource. In particular [the build_file_content](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/ac5b9736356638df6669376be73fa17b05ab1bf9/python/pip_install/repositories.bzl#L72-L85)